# Elixir Operator Overloading: Defining an exclusive range using Macros

Tags: macros, operator-overloading, elixir

To understand the Elixir language better, I wanted to try to do operator overloading, by adding an exclusive range operator, `...`. An example: `1...10` would then create a range from 1 up to but excluding 10 . (e.g. `1...10 == 1..9`)

So, I looked up [the definition of `..`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.2.3/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2446), because the functionality of `...` would of course be very similar.

Mmy module then became:

```
defmodule Sequences.Ranges do

  defmacro first ... last do
    case is_float(first) or is_float(last) or
         is_atom(first) or is_atom(last) or
         is_binary(first) or is_binary(last) or
         is_list(first) or is_list(last) do
      true ->
        raise ArgumentError,
          "ranges (first...last) expect both sides to be integers, " <>
          "got: #{Macro.to_string({:"Sequences.Ranges...", [], [first, last]})}"
      false ->
        case __CALLER__.context do
          nil -> quote do: Elixir.Range.new(unquote(first), unquote(last-1))
          _   -> {:%{}, [], [__struct__: Elixir.Range, first: first, last: (last-1)]}
        end
    end
  end

end
```

However, upon compiling this module, I get the following error:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/sequences/ranges.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/sequences/ranges.ex:6: cannot invoke local .../1 inside match
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1353: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are only a limited number of infix operators that you can define in Elixir:

```
\\, <-, |, ~>>, <<~, ~>, <~, <~>, <|>, <<<, >>>, |||, &&&, and ^^^
```

They are predefined in the parser, but not implemented (or at least are not imported by default). This makes them available for custom implementations, but you can't create your own to add to this list unless you modify and recompile Elixir itself.

`...` is not one of them, so it won't work.

From the comment:

> `|||`, `&&&`, `^^^`, `<<<`, `>>>` and `~~~` are not by default imported, but are part of the default Elixir standard library's `Bitwise` module.

See http://www.rodneyfolz.com/custom-infix-functions-in-elixir/ for more details.

Comment: Let me add to this that `|||`, `&&&`, `^^^`, `<<<`, `>>>` and `~~~` are not by default imported, but are part of the default Elixir standard library's `Bitwise` module. (They are, respecitvely, bitwise or, and, xor, left shift, right shift and not). So in the end only `\\ ` (which is also used to specify a 'default' argument in function clauses), `<-` (which is also used inside for-comprehensions) and `~>`, `<~`, `~>>`, `<<~`, `<~>`, `<|>` remain.

Comment: In the previous list I missed `|` which is overridable, but already used inside lists to construct them/pattern match on them

Comment: For a full list of operators and what they are used for, see https://gist.github.com/Qqwy/3066910db6bf9adcf91b8c5e99148c85